# how to get the email address from auth_user table of requested user id in django 1.5?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I tried following line

```
appraiser_email = auth_user.objects.get(id__exact=2)
```

when i am executing above line it is saying

```
global name 'auth_user' is not defined
```

do i want to define a model auth_user in models.py or is there any other way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 16):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(id=2)
user_email = user.email
```