# Django variable in base.html

Tags: python, django

`base.html` is used as the base template for all other pages. `base.html` has the navigation bar and in the navigation bar, I want to show the number of messages the user received. Thus, I need to have a variable like `{{number_of_messages}}` in the `base.html`.

However, how should I pass this variable to it? Every template extends `base.html` and is rendered by a function. I don't think returning `number_of_messages` in all functions is a good way. Is there better way to implement this? How can I pass this variable to all templates?

Comment: have you look at the django template context processors? perhaps the shortest answer would be to create your own context processors and put it into the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings file.  Shall my comments be an answer instead? REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: hi Yeo, I haven't look at that. Is it possible to achieve this goal by using inclusion tag and putting the inclusion tag inside the base.html?

Comment: I think based on your main question, a variable in a template is called a `context`. `include` tag, does different things, but of course you can pass the context within the included template like `{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}`. But you still need the context somewhere right... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: Hope you managed to solve your problem. Let me know if you still have some issue :-)

Comment: Thanks. I find this good reading and I shall proceed to finish it: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

As long as:

- you use the `render` shortcut in your view (or otherwise take care to use a `RequestContext` to render your response)
- have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting ([as it is by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS))

...then you have the current request's `User` (or `AnonymousUser`) instance available in your template as `{{ user }}` ...I am guessing from there you may be able to access the number of messages directly?

Or perhaps you are using Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)?

This comes with it's own context processor which (as long as you use `render` or `RequestContext`) will make a `{{ messages }}` var (containing the messages for current user) available in your templates. For 'number of messages' you can do `{{ messages|length }}`

If none of these built-in options provide what you need you can either:

- [make your own template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) which will run for every request and make additional variables available to *all* templates (when rendered with a `RequestContext`)
- [make your own template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) which can be used only where needed... of course if this is used in your `base.html` and all templates inherit from `base.html` then it's still going to run for every page.

Answer (score 20):

I find the simplest steps to passing variables to your base templates in django is to add a context_processor.py file like so:

In your app create context_processors.py and declare your variables e.g.:

```
# context_processors.py
def message_processor(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        no_msgs = request.user.profile.msgs
    else:
        no_msgs = 0
    return {
        'messages' : no_msgs
    }
```

Then register your process or under TEMPLATES in your settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                # custom
                'appname.context_processors.message_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And then you will be able to get that variable anywhere in your app as:

```
{{ messages }}
```

Comment: This answer is straight gold. I love you Josh

Comment: Fantastic. This way I could display in **navigation bar** a selection of items based on a DB query. Don't forget to add `request` parameter even if you don't use is in your processor.

Comment: My use case was putting a "Request access" `mailto` link in the generic headline of my site, where I needed the target email to be dynamically pulled from the `auth_user` table.  This technique, combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400767/how-to-get-the-email-address-from-auth-user-table-of-requested-user-id-in-django , allowed me to do it.

Answer (score 18):

You can use tags.

```
#myproject/myproject/templatetags/tags.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def number_of_messages(request):
    return _number
```

In your Base.html

```
{% load tags %}
    {% number_of_messages request %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question, should the tags.py be under templates folder?

Comment: Sorry. tags.py should be under templatetags.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the variable in really *all the views*, then a custom template context processor is probably the best option.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

If you want the variable only in *some of the views*, then you can make those views call a common function that populates the common variables, something like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    params = _common_params(request)
    params.update({
        # params specific to .some_view
    })
    return render_to_response('path/to/template, params)
```

or create a custom decorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def render_with_params():
    def _inner(view_method):
        def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
            params = _common_params(request)
            (template_path, view_params) = view_method(request, *args, **kwargs)
            params.update(view_params)
            return render_to_response(template_path, params, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return wraps(view_method)(_decorator)
    return _inner

@render_with_params()
def some_view(request):
    params = { ... }
    return ('path/to/template', params)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think in my situation, I should use context processor since I need to have the variable in all templates. Thank you!