# unable to display form inside modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-2.0

I am having trouble displaying password change from inside modal window.

I can see the modal window but I don't see the call happening to `def change_password` even though I have mentioned it in the `action` of my modal.

Views.py

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'usermgmt/change-password.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

modal dialog:

```
<div id="passwordChangeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="{% url 'usermgmt:change_password_page' %}" method="post" id="changepassword" class="form">
              {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
          </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
<h1>Hello From Change Password</h1>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

This is how I am calling the modal:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css'%}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#passwordChangeModal">Change Password</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div id="passwordChangeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'usermgmt:change_password_page' %}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div class="container">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are showing two different modals, one without `{{ form }}` and another with `{{ form }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in the lack of submit button in modal's form unless you  submit that form via JS.

EDIT: added workaround of your problem with accessibility of `PasswordChangeForm` instance in your base template via adding a context processor.
I created file `context_processors.py` in my app's folder (in your case it is `usermgmt`) with new context processor called `password_form` (you are free to use any name, just be sure to reflect this change also in `settings.py`, more details further):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm


def password_form(request):
    return {
        'pwd_form': PasswordChangeForm(request.user),
    }
```

Then I inserted a line into core `settings.py` TEMPLATES/OPTIONS/context_processors section, so that it looks like this now:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        'usermgmt.context_processors.password_form'
    ],
},
```

Now you can use `pwd_form` in any template, including your `base.html`. I worked out following modal section of `base.html`, based on your code (note comments):

```
<div id="passwordChangeModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <!-- without this div I wasn't able to close opened modal -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'change_password' %}" class="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ pwd_form }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> <!-- note lack of data-dismiss="modal" - with this attr set I wasn't able to submit form as modal just got closed all the time - probably because of the precedence of modal-related attrs, but I couldn't find any docs regarding this behaviour -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>`. It shows `Save` button in the modal dialog but not the form.

Comment: @Asdfg ok, can you provide more details about how you call the modal? Where is your code under "modal dialog" actually sittting (in which file)? My guesses without answers on the above questions are that you show this modal on some page (not change_password page) where there is no `form` template variable or your modal code is sitting somewhere out of the template (in some .js file maybe) and thus doesn't have access to template variable `form`.

Comment: @Asdfg I think you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062560/django-variable-in-base-html). If you don't come up with a solution, I will do it a bit later today

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.