# How to get values from another app from the database in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I get the value from another app and display that value in the template present in another app of a project in Django?
I have this project dir structure:-

```
-News-Scrape
  - accounts
  - education
  - home
  - news
    - models.py(The value is present here)
    - views.py
    - templates
  - static
  - templates
    - base.html(I want to display a value here which is present in the `news` app)
```

Since the `base.html` file is out of the app, how can I display any particular value from `news` app's the database in this page.

Here's the `models.py`(from news app) file:-

```
from django.db import models

class PageView(models.Model):
    hits    =   models.IntegerField(default=0) #I need this value to be displayed in my `base.html` file
```

Here's the `views.py`(from news app) file:-

```
def news_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if(PageView.objects.count()<=0):
        x=PageView.objects.create()
        x.save()
    else:
        x=PageView.objects.all()[0]
        x.hits=x.hits+1
        x.save()
    context={}

    context = {
       'object_list': queryset,
       'page': x.hits
    }
    return render(request, 'news_list.html', context)
```

If the `base.html` file would be inside the `news` app I could easily get the value by `{{object.<id_label>}}`, But this is not working when the `base.html` file is present outside the app.
I am a beginner in Django and having a tough time figuring out a way to achieve this.

Comment: What does your news_list.html and base.html look like? If you're extending base.html from news_list, it shouldn't be a problem to access the context from there.

Comment: I am extending `base.html` in `news_list.html`. because I have the header and footer present in the `base.html` file and I want ot display a value in the footer section of my `base.html` file

Comment: I think you should be able to access this value from the base.html as is. If you want to show this value on every page you view to the user, you'll have to make sure `'page'` is in the context of every template extending `base.html`.

The best way to do this is using a custom context processor, as shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062560/django-variable-in-base-html

Comment: you must import `PageView` in your `views.py` file

Answer (score 0):

> News-Scrape
>
> - `accounts`
> - `education`
> - `home`
> - `news`
>
>   - `templates`
>
>     - `news`
>
>       - `base.html` or your html files
>   - `models.py`
>   - `views.py`

you can create individual template folder for every app in your project