# Error: Reverse for 'coach_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: - Unable to resolve

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to create a directory-based website. I have created a list view, and I have created a detail view that populates when you click on an item in the list view. But, I also want to use a similar detail view to serve the user's own data to them on a profile page. I have done this by creating a queryset in a separate view.

The problem is, is that I don't seem to be able to configure the urls and template tag correctly to get it to show on the page, and I am just getting the following error:

```
Reverse for 'coach_profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['coach/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/profile$']
```

I am trying to access this page from a link on the navbar called your profile. The template tags I am trying are as follows

```
href="{% 'coach_profile' %}">Your Coach Profile</a>
href="{% 'coach_profile' coach.id %}">Your Coach Profile</a>
href="{% 'coach_profile' coach.pk %}">Your Coach Profile</a>
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import CoachListView, CoachDetailView, CoachProfileView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CoachListView.as_view(), name='coach_list'),
    path('<uuid:pk>', CoachDetailView.as_view(), name='coach_detail'),
    path('<uuid:pk>/profile/', CoachProfileView.as_view(), name='coach_profile'),
    ]
```

**`views.py`**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Profile


class CoachListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'coach_list'
    template_name = 'coach/coach_list.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'


class CoachDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'coach_detail'
    template_name = 'coach/coach_detail.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'


class CoachProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'coach_profile'
    template_name = 'coach/coach_profile.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return Profile.objects.all()
        else:
            return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

import uuid


class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('coach_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**`Templates (_base.html)`**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'coach_profile' coach.id %}">Your Coach Profile</a>
<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Log Out</a>
{% else %}
<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Log In</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
```

---

This previously asked question solved my query.

[Django variable in base.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062560/django-variable-in-base-html)

Comment: Where does the template code you included reside in?

Comment: It sits in _base.html

Comment: After looking into this it bit more, it had more to do with where I was accessing the variable in _base.html. I've edited my answer above to show the questions that answered mine.

Comment: You might want to consider putting your solution here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which view this template is related to but if this template is related to your `CoachListView` you should do something like:

```
{% for obj in coach_list %}
<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'coach_profile' obj.id %}">Your Coach Profile</a>
{% endfor %}
```

because `coach_list` is a queryset and for geting id of an object you should iterate through it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This solved my problem in so much that the link now works. But as I have multiple users, this creates multiple 'Your Coach Profile' links on the navbar, with only one being accessible to the logged in user. I would like there to be only one version of the link related to the logged in user, hence I'm not sure the for loop is the correct approach.

FYI coach_list was a typo, I have edited the question to fix this. The template tag relates to CoachProfileView which is called 'coach_profile' in the context object name of the view.